# App freezes for a while using google maps on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, freeze

I am using google maps within multiview application. When I switch between the tabs having google map, my app freezes for a while. After waiting for a while it switches to another controller as it should. Can anyone help me why is this happening?

I am running the Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.6.1.6332 and testing on an Iphone 4 with iOS 7.1.

This problem is only in the case of iPhone. App is running fine in simulator.

Can anyone find a work-around for this, or is it something that can only be resolved with the next update on the framework?

Comment: I am still stuck on this.Anybody please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got solution, just replaced old google map SDKs with newer version and problem disappeared.